# Package installation impossible in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to setup a raspberry pi 3. I want to install and run a node code, but I have a problem while installing packages with npm.

I tried several times with several versions of node (including the armhf latest and an older one), but I always get the following error (while installing groove [npm install groove]

```
groove@2.5.1 install /home/pi/node_modules/groove  node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/pi/node_modules/groove/build'   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/groove/src/groove.o In file included from ../src/groove.cc:4:0: ../src/file.h:6:27: fatal error: groove/groove.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type  #include <groove/groove.h>
                           ^ compilation terminated. groove.target.mk:95: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/groove/src/groove.o' failed make: *** [Release/obj.target/groove/src/groove.o] Error 1 make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/node_modules/groove/build' gyp ERR! build error  gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR! stack   at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23) gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7) gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12) gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.50-v7+ gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/node_modules/groove gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3 gyp ERR! not ok  npm ERR! Linux
4.4.50-v7+ npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "groove" npm ERR! node v4.2.1 npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! groove@2.5.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the groove@2.5.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'. npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the groove package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild npm ERR! You can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls groove npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
```

The npm-debug.log is the following:
http://pastebin.com/M5jRwiFX

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried giving it permissions? (`sudo`)

Comment: With permissions it returns a slightly different error: http://pastebin.com/3h1uVuwE

Comment: Have you installed libgroove library first?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `groove/groove.h`
Try installing libgroove-dev

Comment: I tried to install it from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/armhf/libgroove-dev/4.3.0-2build1 
by running 

`wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/armhf/libgroove-dev/4.3.0-2build1`

and 

`sudo dpkg -i libgroove-dev_4.3.0-2_armhf.deb`

but I have dependencies issues (sudo apt-get -f install doesn't solve them)

Comment: Try this: `# apt-add-repository ppa:andrewrk/libgroove
# apt-get update
# apt-get install libgroove-dev`

Comment: `dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de libgroove-dev:armhf :
 libgroove-dev:armhf dépend de libgroove4 (= 4.3.0-2) ; cependant :
 Le paquet libgroove4:armhf n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet libgroove-dev:armhf (--install) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 libgroove-dev:armhf
`
It's in french, but it says that libgroove-dev:armhf depends on libgroove4, but the former is not configurated... I thought the armhf version is the only one I had to have

Comment: no unfortunately you need both the dev and the regular package, did you try the repository mentioned earlier?

Comment: The command `apt-add-repository ppa:andrewrk/libgroove` only returns: command not found

Comment: So before that command, run ` sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties` ran fine, but then `apt-add-repository ppa:andrewrk/libgroove`returns me the following error: http://pastebin.com/Vc31mAEz